# config.xml front name not working while entering front name in url

Tags: magento

I have created my custom module that is working fine at backend(Add,Edit,Delete,List) but while I enter frontname in url it shows me page not found error. below is my code

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <ydg_cylinderworksheet>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>ydg_Cylinderworksheet</module>
                <frontName>cylinder-worksheet</frontName>
            </args>
        </ydg_cylinderworksheet>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <ydg_cylinderworksheet>
                <file>ydg_cylinderworksheet.xml</file>
            </ydg_cylinderworksheet>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <ydg_Cylinderworksheet>
                <files>
                    <default>ydg_Cylinderworksheet.csv</default>
                </files>
            </ydg_Cylinderworksheet>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
```

Comment: check your files permission is properly or no.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but, Actually I am new to magento How can I do this? should I change permission for only config.xml file or entire app folder? @Supravat

Comment: get the file  & folder permission of your instance.

Comment: As you are a beginner I suggest you to follow the steps Alan Storm has mentioned over here. http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world . If you follow all the steps properly and have patience you will certainly get the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needd to change your routers tag in your etc/config.xml

```
<routers>
            <cylinderworksheet>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ydg_Cylinderworksheet</module>
                    <frontName>cylinder-worksheet</frontName>
                </args>
            </cylinderworksheet>

 </routers>
```

....

Comment: Agarwal: Thanks I tried this code too and It's working fine.... But there was problem with my controller name I changed it to IndexController and it's worked for me after trying so much now I got the real concept how it works.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code

```
 <frontend>
    <routers>
    <cylinderworksheet>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>ydg_Cylinderworksheet</module>
            <frontName>cylinderworksheet</frontName>
        </args>
    </cylinderworksheet>
    </routers>
    .........
```